# как вместо url .../account.jsp установить .../account?name="name"?

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlet

Можно ли в servlet или в .jsp каким-то образом установить параметры url, чтобы изменить url как в заголовке?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы пишете в url …/account.jsp то вы обходите ваш сервлет и сразу получаете .jsp.

Чтобы обратиться к сервлету нужно указать его в web.xml. А в сервлете прикрепить к ответу jsp.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Servlets.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

HelloServler:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.print(req.getParametr("name"));
        req.getRequestDispatcher("hello.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Далее можно спокойно писать в url параметры и получать к ним доступ.